# How to disable pinging during tests in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ping

I have a class that uses `My.Computer.Network.Ping` to get a boolean value on whether a IP address or hostname is reachable.

However, when I'm testing that class, I want to disable pinging so that during the test whenever I run the `My.Computer.Network.Ping` it will always return `false` or throw some kind of exception.

I have tried the following, but I still get a `true` returned (meaning, the attempts to disable ping didn't work)

```
Dim restricited As New System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.None)
    Dim mySocketPermission1 As New SocketPermission(PermissionState.None)
    Dim myWebPermission As New WebPermission(PermissionState.None)
    myWebPermission.Demand()
    mySocketPermission1.Demand()
    Dim ping As New PingOptions()
    ping.DontFragment = True
    ping.Ttl = 1

*attempt to ping here*
*but doesn't return the "ping failed" I wanted*
```

Any ideas?
Edit: 'm using VS2010 with .Net 4.0 Framework (full)

Comment: create a moq of the class doing the ping?  Use interception if you can?

Comment: Could you modify your code to return `false` when a command line parameter, environment variable, registry value, etc. is set and let your test method disable pinging this way?

Comment: @PaulB. I could but I'd really want to have it in the tests and leave the class alone

Comment: You could also try to modify the hosts file (assuming you are using host names and not IP addresses) but this seems to be a rather ugly approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You could also try to modify the hosts file (assuming you are using host names and not IP addresses) but this seems to be a rather ugly approach... – Paul B. Jun 9 at 15:02

Paul B's answer did it for me. I'm testing on Win7 and XP, but XP seems to be fussy when using the host file method. Works fine on Win7.

Paul is the man.